# Why my sitemap.xml is on error status on searchConsole

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

im using [nodejs sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) library for building my sitmaps.xml.

Every thing is woking well on my code and

- Here is my [sitemapIndex](https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/sitemap.xml)
- Exemple of [site map](https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/1)

But unfortunately on searchconsole since 2 February i have an [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCv6r.png).

Bad namespace

=> The namespace is incorrectly specified in your index file or sitemap.

So can any one help me?

Comment: So, Google says just that, "You have an error", and it doesn't explain anything else? Have you expanded all collapsed elements and clicked all the links?

Comment: Error = Bad namespace
=> The namespace is incorrectly specified in your index file or sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing **xmlns** attribute from both *loc* and *lastmod* tags? For example on your XML sitemap index:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/statics.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/1</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/ara/1</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/2</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/ara/2</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/3</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://sitemap.tmaps.tn/address/ara/3</loc>
        <lastmod>2023-03-16</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: Looks like they are still there. Are you sure they were removed? Also, have you tried to send it back to Google to verify it?

Comment: Hey think you. It's working